# Maximizing a Ratio/Percent

Tags: linear-programming, cvxpy, linearization

I'm using `cvxpy` to model a problem.
Inside a very large and complex LP, I create two continuous, affine (unconstrained) expressions:`x` and `y`.
Due to how they are created, I know that `0 < x < y <= U`. Obviously: `x/y < 1`.

In my LP *objective*, how do I ***maximize*** the ratio `x/y`?

Things I tried:

- Maximizing `x*cp.inv_pos(Y)` states my problem is non DCP (also if I try to minimize the inverse)
- I found various LP formulations for maximizing ratios (e.g. [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/ratio.htm) or [here](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_LinearProgrammingTricks.pdf#page=8)) but these requires rewriting the *constraints* on all the terms in the expressions for `x` - I have no idea how to do that with `cvxpy`.
  If this is the way to go then an example would be very helpful!

Comment: You may want to have a look at Dinkelbach's algorithm.

Comment: Try solving the problem via ``prob.solve(qcp=True)``. Maximizing a ratio is DQCP (one of the problem types solvable via cvxpy).

Comment: @steven: Unfortunately, the rest of my problem is not DQCP.